# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex

Tags: android, android-logcat, illegalargumentexception

Same Application Work in Android 7 and Failed in Android 8.

On an activity i am retrieving data from Fire-base database. when Fire-base database is empty then no error occurred and error occurred when it's have data's , I searched error but never got any solution for that.

logcat :-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex
        at android.graphics.Outline.setConvexPath(Outline.java:284)
        at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.getOutline(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:387)
        at android.view.ViewOutlineProvider$1.getOutline(ViewOutlineProvider.java:38)
        at android.view.View.rebuildOutline(View.java:14960)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundBounds(View.java:19416)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19381)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19183)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:4703)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4107)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
```

code of item_people.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/icon_avata"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/people_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:text="link"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNickname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="name"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Same application work in android 7 and when i tried in android 8 it fails !

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier i added code please check it !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, the first few lines tell a story:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex
        at android.graphics.Outline.setConvexPath(Outline.java:284)
        at android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable.getOutline(AdaptiveIconDrawable.java:387)
        at android.view.ViewOutlineProvider$1.getOutline(ViewOutlineProvider.java:38)
        at android.view.View.rebuildOutline(View.java:14960)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundBounds(View.java:19416)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19381)
```

- 3rd line mentions `AdaptiveIconDrawable`
- 7th line mentions `View.drawBackground()`

---

Searching for `AdaptiveIconDrawable` tells us that this is a new Android 8 feature:

- [Android Developers reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AdaptiveIconDrawable.html)

That explains why your code works on Android 7 but crashes on 8. On Android 7 the system does not use adaptive icons, but instead uses a normal PNG. On Android 8 it will use an adaptive icon if you have supplied one.

There seems to be something wrong with the new icon, or it just doesn't work where you are using it.

---

Next we need to find out what background is breaking...

Looking at your `CardView` layout, you are setting your launcher icon (on Android 8 this is likely to be your `AdaptiveIconDrawable`) onto your `CircleImageView` background.

That is where the crash is happening - either the icon is not valid, or `CircleImageView` does not support it when used this way.

A fix would be to include a PNG icon in your app that will work as the background in this case.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think the problem may be in this line: android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round. Çözümü de @drawable/image.png

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your icon is set up properly, try setting the icon for CircleImageView using `android:src` instead of `android:background`.